# Facebook library for Android Tablet with Honeycomb (3.2)

Tags: facebook, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet, single-sign-on

I wrote an android app for my samsung nexus (2.3) that uses Facebook single-sign-on.  I did everything as it was shown in the tutorial on Facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/.
Everything worked perfect.

I took the same application and installed it on my asus eeepad transformer and everything worked fine except for the Facebook functions. When something uses the facebook library the application crashes immediately.

I created a new Android-Project for the Tablet (3.2) but the problem is still the same. Is there a different library for tablets?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the request method from AsyncFacebookRunner instead of the request method from facebook class.

But I have no clue why it worked on the cellphone without the AsyncFacebookRunner.

Mischa